# FileNotFound(Invalid Path) in Implicit Intent File Sharing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I am trying to access a file from Movies Directory named "myfile.mp4" for sharing using implicit Intent

but this is not working..

I think i am not getting the correct path? right?

My code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES+"/filename.mp4"));
            Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: Not a correct path, yes. You should start with Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).

Comment: should i use uri.parse or remove it?

Comment: Yes parse it....

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated.

Comment: Does not matter. It works fine. And the one i mentioned too.

Comment: its matter because i am using Min SDK level 23 and this path is deprecated in Android Sdk level 26, and now a day more than 60% device is running with Android 10 so its matter

Comment: No it does not. Not even on Android 10 devices or Android 11 emulators. Deprecated wont say that it does not work. It works.

Comment: `more than 60% device is running with Android 10 ` That i do not believe.

Comment: ur solution is not working..

Comment: Please post the new code in a new code block in your post. And 'not working' is not very informative. And remember: in my first comment i said `You should start with` so there is more to come.